# How to reduce ubuntu 18.04 ram usage

Tags: 18.04, ram

A time ago i was on Ubuntu 16.04 i tried to update to 18.04 .

The PC just freezes and i turned it off.
When i turned it on, the screen showed 18.04 .

And the session manager was now gdm but it didn't work i started xserver form a tty.
And Ubuntu ran gnome shell, for be fair that error gave me all that i wanted.

The """new""" gnome shell that's super clean without the nasty ubuntu dock.
Several functions of Ubuntu 18.04 without several useless processes, etc, etc, etc.

The whole system was using 600 Mb ram without open any applications.
But for one error that i wasn't able to solve(couldn't launch graphical application from the terminal because an error in wayland or something i don't well remember), i had no other choice than upgrade to the actual ubuntu 18.04 and now i'm trying to make the system run using less than 1 Gb ram.

Even removing evolution and several processes seems just impossible.
And idk what are several gsd processes that wasn't before, also why gnome-shell now uses almost 100 MB ram, when before it was using about 20 MBs.

Gnome-session is in the 3.28.1 version and it says that's the last version, i heard something about a huge ram leak in this version but i don't know how to update.

Do you know how to make Ubuntu run using less ram.

Comment: First, you should use a resource monitor to see if you can identify any errant processes that are taking more RAM than they should. Also, are you telling us that your upgrade to 18.04 failed halfway through?  If so, you could have corrupted operating system files and your best path may be to reinstall the OS.  If you only have 1GB of RAM, I would suggest not using GNOME at all and moving to an Ubuntu flavor with a DE that is not so heavy. Lubuntu and Xubuntu are good lightweight alternatives

Comment: Why do you want to reduce your RAM usage ? If you just run out of RAM often, you may want to increase your SWAP space.

Comment: Be careful removing things, `evolution` the MUA is easy to remove being an option mail program for GNOME, however the evolution-dataserver is a backend for GNOME and thus required. When talking about removing `evolution` I hope you were talking about the MUA or mail user application.  Does your PC meet the minimum specs?  Ubuntu 17.10 & higher had higher requirements than did prior releases (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) otherwise lighter desktops are usually suggested (they're unsupported on *bionic* though now as come with 3 years of supported life)

Comment: @Nmath i said that the first time that i tryed to update to 18.04 failed through, now i reinstalled, also i have 2GB RAM i'll considerate moving to a lightweight flavor.

Comment: @Programmer I want it to play brawlhalla, and use more swap just don't help because is soooo much slower, it causes fps issues.

Comment: @guiverc i deleted all evolution libs, maybe i made a mistake, i'll search about it